# How to lower Lambda polling on SQS? High invocation usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have about 4 lambda's that are triggered by 4 individual SQS queues in a 1:1 mapping. They are triggered via [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html)

I checked my Billing today and I'm over the 1M free invocation limit:
[image]

I check the monitoring of a single SQS and it looks like the `Number of Empty Receives` is pretty high:

[image]

I googled around and I believe this means Event Source is polling the queue to see if it can invoke a lambda functionand because it's empty, it results in an "empty receive".

I'm not sure if there's a way to increase the polling wait time or reduce the number of times the polling can happen but looks like I'm hitting the 1M limit pretty quickly.

Comment: No, there is not much you can do. Pooling of SQS in Event Source Mapping is fully managed by AWS. You would have to stop using ESM and pull the SQS yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario what I would suggest you is to increase **MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds** this will result in long polling and less burning of CPU cycles.

You can refer to this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource

Comment: Looks like this might work. I have a batch size of 1, do you know if I set `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` to 5 minutes, if it will wait 5 minutes for a batch of 1, but if it gets 1 job, it will immediately begin another long-poll?

Comment: I looked at the docs, I don't think `MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds` will work since this is on the Lambda side and can save requests there. On the SQS side, the `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` is available but the max is 20 seconds, which is already the default.